# Python built in sum() function with numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand how the sum function is able to add numpy arrays without using the np.sum function in numpy. The code in question is the following

Input

```
a = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])]
sum(a)
```

Output:

```
array([4, 6])
```

The built-in sum function in python takes an iterable and sums the values from left to right. I am assuming the built-in sum uses the dunder add special method of each of the objects, e.g., int, to add each of the items together. So the only way I see this being possible is the np.array object overriding the dunder add special method to be able to use the built-in sum function with arrays.

Comment: That is not what that code outputs.

Comment: It's doing `np.array([1, 2])+np.array([3, 4])`.. `np.sum([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([3, 4])], axis=0)` does the same thing

Comment: Have you tried `np.array([1, 2]) + np.array([3, 4])`?

Comment: the output of the above is `[4 6]` which come from `1+3` and `2+4`...

Answer (score 0):

`sum((a, b))` essentially calculates `0 + a + b`.  Since in the case of the arguments you gave it, `0 + a + b` makes sense, that's the results you got.  You can add a constant to a numpy array, and you can add two numpy arrays that have a compatible size.

Comment: the output will be `[4 6]` and not what the OP has posted in the question...

Comment: @D.L. I should have paid more attention to OPs post. I run it and get [4,6], exactly what I expected.

Comment: Sorry guys, I switched the question to the correct output

Comment: Hello Frank Yellin. Does the python build in sum function call the dunder add special method though? How does it actually add the array values since the built in sum function is not a numpy function?

Comment: Presumably a np array has both __radd__ and a __add__ method. I do not know the precise implementation of sum(), but I presume it uses PyObject_Add.

Comment: Hello Frank, 

Thanks for the answer. That was originally my question about the special dunder add methods